# Case-insensitively check if at least N columns in a range hold an "x"

Tags: microsoft-excel

PART 1)

I need help writing a statement that checks if requirements are done. If they are, then it will highlight their name. Below is what I have started. It is VERY sloppy and would like to know how to simplify it.

IF(((B3="X")             OR             (B3="x"))         AND         ((C3="X")             OR             (C3="x"))        AND        ((D3="X")             OR             (D3="x"))         AND        ((E3="X")             OR             (E3="x"))         AND        ((F3="X")             OR             (F3="x"))         AND        ((G3="X")             OR             (G3="x"))       AND       ((H3="X")     OR     (H3="x"))) AND    (((I3="X")    OR    (I3="x"))   OR   ((J3="X")   OR   (J3="x"))   OR   ((K3="X")   OR   (K3="x"))   OR   ((L3="X")   OR   (L3="x"))   OR   ((M3="X")   OR   (M3="x"))   OR   ((N3="X")   OR   (N3="x"))   OR   ((O3="X")   OR   (O3="x"))   OR   ((P3="X")   OR   (P3="x"))   OR   ((Q3="X")   OR   (Q3="x"))   OR   ((R3="X")   OR   (R3="x"))   OR   ((S3="X")   OR   (S3="x"))   OR   ((T3="X")   OR   (T3="x"))   OR   ((U3="X")   OR   (U3="x")))

This checks to make sure there is an "x" in each cell B3 through H3 and then it checks if there is an "x" in at least one of the cells I3 through U3. This is a checklist to keep track of scouts completing their rank requirements. Once B-H is done and one of I-U is completed... Their name turns green.

PART 2)

The same thing but I want the second part to check if at least 2 of that section are complete. (all of B-H and 2 of I-U)

Thank you and I am sorry for butchering this code. It has been a very long time since I touched any programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example

=COUNTIF(B3:H3,"=x",B3:H3,"=X")

to get the number of x, and as the amount is known (B - H = 7):

=IF(COUNTIF(B3:H3,"=x",B3:H3,"=X")=7,"good","not finished")

Similar for the other part.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried it and a few variations but I just can't figure out how to implement it. Am I able to attach my spreadsheet to this forum? maybe it would help if someone had a "hands on" approach.

Comment: I just corrected the semicolons to commas in my answer, maybe that broke it (the standard setting is commas as separators; I use semicolon, and I forget that every time I post..).

Comment: Thank You! I ended up using: =IF((COUNTIF(C6:I6,"x")=7)       AND       (IF(COUNTIF(J6:V6,"x")>=1))) It seems that it doesn't matter if it is capital or lower case.